# linux dual nic internet access

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have a linux server with two NICs. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the default route set so that internet traffic will exit one NIC and not try to use the other.  Here is what I think is the relevant configuration items.

```
cat /etc/systemd/network/10-eth0.network

[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Gateway=172.31.16.129
Address=172.31.16.149/27
DHCP=no

[DHCP]
UseDNS=false

cat /etc/systemd/network/10-eth1.network

[Match]
Name=eth1
[Network]
Gateway=192.168.100.1
Address=192.168.100.2/24
DHCP=no
[DHCP]
UseDNS=false


route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         172.31.16.129   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.31.16.128   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

I've tried create a specific persistent route to the 172.xx network and deleting the quad 0 route.. that didn't work.  I know this is a rudimentary thing, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Ultimately, I want to be able to SSH into the box using the 172.xxx but the box should use the 192.168.xxx to get to everything else.. like the internet.  Sorry.. not so good at the networking stuff I guess.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't add a default gateway to the 172 interface in the first place.

Comment: I tried that.. and then I lost connectivity.. I must be missing something else ?

Comment: You're missing information here then.  You need a route from the source where you're trying to connect from and that's it.  If it's the same network, you don't need any route.  If it's a different network, you need a route for that network.

Comment: Oh, duh.. I was adding a route to the same network.. I needed a route to the source network.. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

1. Defualt Gateway for a NIC adds a 0.0.0.0/0 route for that IP, aka a default route.
2. Router engines usually (but not always) route to the most specific route they can find, and anything is more specific than 0.0.0.0/0
3. As such, you can only have one 0.0.0.0/0 route on a specific system. All other routes have to be more specific, in your case you could have a 0.0.0.0/0 route on the NIC you want to use for everything but management, and then a route to for example 172.16.0.0/12 for your other NIC (but only if this is your network setup and everything in the 172.16.0.0/12 is indeed behind that NIC)